# Erro após subir apk na play store

Tags: ionic, ionic3, google-play

Após eu gerar o apk e subir no site a revisão me retorna o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz todo o processo da página: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html não houve nenhum erro até gerar o apk e incluir a assinatura. O que devo fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Isso não é um erro, é um "warning" avisando que o seu app não é um bundle, segundo a própria google:

> O Android App Bundle é o novo formato de publicação oficial do Android, que oferece uma maneira mais eficiente de criar e lançar apps. O Android App Bundle traz mais facilidade para você oferecer uma ótima experiência em um app menor, o que pode gerar mais instalações e reduzir as desinstalações. É fácil mudar. Você não precisa refatorar o código para começar a aproveitar as vantagens de um app menor. Depois da mudança, você poderá contar com o desenvolvimento de apps modulares e com a entrega de recursos personalizáveis.

https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle

Até onde sei, não tem como fazer tal tipo de app com o ionic.